# How to bind to web sockets server from old browser that does not support HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, browser, websocket

I am building a WEB application which waits a message from my admin web application server.

I solved this by using html5 websocket programming ;

But not all my clients do have html5 support in thier browsers. So I am searching for a way to bind to the websocket server from an old browser even in a low level programming (lower than websocket) in javascript .

Is this possible to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Socket.io](http://socket.io/#browser-support) suports the most browsers, but unfortunately not all.

Comment: As i see socket.io is ntegrated with the node.js server side but my websocket server is implemented in php exactly [ratchet](http://socketo.me). Can I use it with php

Comment: i don't know about ratchet, but you can use this one in server side http://elephant.io/#usage

Comment: socket.io handles the websocket in old browsers, so it finds a way for old browsers to replace the use of websocket. With ratchet, as i see, it only allows you to use websockets, not other way, so i don't think socket.io can communicate with ratchet

Comment: Socket.io does not implement WebSocket for old browsers, but a HTTP long-poll based fallback.

Answer (score 2):

For old browsers without WebSocket, but Flash, there is [this fallback WebSocket implementation in Flash](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js).

For old IE, there is Google Chrome Frame.

Both should work with Ratchet (since they make the old browser actually speak WebSocket).